# How to use another variable values as labels on date x-axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a ggplot using **date x axis** but I would like to show their values from another variable instead of dates.

df

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


df <- read_rds("https://github.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/blob/main/vaccine_milestones.rds?raw=true")
```

```
df

  Updated.On cr_bin days_to_next_10cr_vacc
  <date>     <fct>  <drtn>                
1 2021-04-11 10 Cr  85 days               
2 2021-05-27 20 Cr  46 days               
3 2021-06-24 30 Cr  28 days               
4 2021-07-18 40 Cr  24 days               
5 2021-08-06 50 Cr  19 days               
6 2021-08-25 60 Cr  19 days               
7 2021-09-07 70 Cr  13 days               
8 2021-09-18 80 Cr  11 days               
9 2021-10-02 90 Cr  14 days
```

```
df %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = Updated.On, y = days_to_next_10cr_vacc)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_date(aes(labels = cr_bin))
```

Also tried: `scale_x_date(aes(labels = c("10","20","30","40","50","60","70","80","90")))`

[image]

In the plot on the x axis I would like to have values displayed from **cr_bin** instead of dates as `10 Cr, 20 cr, 30 Cr ... so on 90 Cr`.

I have tried above code but I am not sure what else to use in place of **labels** to get desired results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set breaks for labels. I'm using `unique`, just in case there might be duplicate rows.

Also note conversion off `difftime` to `integer`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- read_rds("https://github.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/blob/main/vaccine_milestones.rds?raw=true")

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Updated.On, y = as.integer(days_to_next_10cr_vacc))) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = unique(df$Updated.On), labels = unique(df$cr_bin))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: obviously this only works if unique(date) and unique(cr_bin) have the same length!

Comment: thanks @tjebo for helping on this. I initially tried with `breaks` as well like: `scale_x_date(aes(breaks = Updated.On, labels = cr_bin))` but that didn't work either as I was preprocessing the data & then piping all to the `ggplot`. May be it doesn't work well with `aes()` and its better to save preprocessed data (the one that I shared for this post) & then refer them like as you did above `scale_x_date(breaks = df$Updated.On, labels = df$cr_bin)`